# How to call Python in PHP

Tags: php, python

I want to get files in PHP, re-format, and transfer to Python,
like:

```
<?php
   $files = $_FILES;
   // Re-format and send to Python
?>
Python:
def get_files(file)
  // Do something on files
  return result
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Sure, just write a transpiler.

Comment: In short, no. PHP and Python store information differently; they are not compatible and cannot share code in the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a project called [Pip-Python](https://www.csh.rit.edu/~jon/projects/pip/) in PHP.

You can check it out.

Also I don't know why people vote down this question because there are more than one way to achieve this.

You can use the 'exec' function to run a Python script via PHP, but it can be dangerous.

You can also checkout [the backquote operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php).

I suggest you either write your own re-format function in PHP or modify someone else's function that does the same thing in PHP. It is also going to be hard to maintain code in the future if you combine two different languages.

Comment: _"Also I don't know why people vote-down this question"_ Because it's extremely vague and poorly stated, showing no research effort. _"because there are more than one way to achieve this."_ That has nothing to do with the quality of the question

Comment: Well, thank you for your comment. At least I learned something new.

Comment: You've been here for four years! Here's some reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote